# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy to prevent download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I built an e-learning website and used Amazon S3 for storing the files.

**I want:**

> • Website visitors can watch the videos  •    They cannot download the
>   videos**

**Which policy should I add to the bucket policy, sir?**

I used the below policy but this keep video in private, so they both cannot watch and download.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1459891655092",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1459891443631",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/public/*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: The video has to be first downloaded before it can be watched. S3 is not a video streaming service.

Comment: Cheer, helloV. How about using .ht access to prevent the right click, sir?

Comment: How do your users "watch the videos"? What technology do you use to serve the videos to them? Are videos it embedded in an HTML page, or served somehow? Do you want *anyone* to be allowed to *watch*, or only select users? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

S3 can provide for streaming of protected content. This is a very common request.

First you transcode your videos into HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) using Amazon Elastic Transcoder. The user then uses a video player or browser that supports HLS that connects to your web server. The content stored on S3 is encrypted. HLS breaks a video up into many small segments of multiple resolutions. The video changes dynamically during playback based upon many factors such as changes in Internet speed, device resolution, etc. CloudFront is not required to deliver HLS videos.

Take a look at Amazon's Elastic Transcoder and Apple's HLS viewer to get you started. Even Microsoft Edge supports HLS.

Comment: Thank, John Hanley :)

Comment: I put my video encoded as a series of data files and with an index using AET and tried to stream it. Embedding it in an HTML page removes the "right click/download" button so that's fine. However, I can simply use ffmpeg and download it. `ffmpeg -i https://path/to/the/.m3u/file foo.mp4` and then I can watch `foo.mp4`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use S3 policy to prevent download because user must download to view it. S3 also does not support streaming. But you can combine with [AWS Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) to stream your S3 videos. You just set permission to allow AWS Cloudfront get your S3 videos, then Cloudfront will cache them at the edges. User can stream videos via Cloudfront URLs.

[Read this for more detail](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-amazon-cloudfront-for-video-streaming/)

> The first option is very easy to implement and is supported by just
>   about every mobile device and desktop.  All you need to do is to put
>   your content in an S3 bucket and create a CloudFront distribution that
>   points to the bucket. Your user’s video player will use CloudFront
>   URLs (accessible as part of the distribution) to request the video
>   file. The request will be directed to the best edge location, based on
>   the user’s location. CloudFront will serve the video from its cache,
>   fetching it from the S3 bucket if it is not already cached. This
>   option has a couple of downsides. It makes inefficient use of your
>   viewer’s bandwidth. If the user doesn’t bother to watch the entire
>   video, content would never be seen is still downloaded. Skipping ahead
>   or fast-forwarding also necessitates downloading of content that may
>   never be seen.